# Camera app for iOS that can simulate fields of view from different sensor sizes and focal lengths

Tags: ios, camera

I'm looking for a camera app for iOS that could simulate fields of view obtained with user-specified combinations of "virtual" sensor sizes and focal lengths (that is, what a DSLR with such specs would see) and take pictures cropped down to the corresponding pixel dimensions. Obviously it would be limited to simulate longer lenses / narrower fields of view than what the built-in camera natively produces, as no software can increase the physical size of the sensor.

There are a bunch of "director's viewfinder" apps geared towards cinematography that do the FoV simulation part. However, most of them either can't take pictures at all or are overly constrained in that ability, making them unsuitable as camera apps.

There is one such viewfinder app, [Cadrage](https://www.cadrage.app/), that almost does what I'm looking for: it can simulate about any sensor/lens combination and allows taking photos with the resulting crop factor, optionally without any framing markers or other burnt-in information so that the result is a usable photograph. However, instead of simply cropping the image to the desired size, it scales the cropped image up to match the built-in camera's native image size (i.e. if the device has a 12 MP camera and your settings would call for a crop to 4 MP, you'll get an upscaled 12 MP image that only contains 4 MP's worth of information), which is wasteful and can produce unwanted artifacts. Moreover, Cadrage's UX naturally reflects the app's stated purpose as a framing preview tool, and is not ideal for a camera as such.

I'm looking the app primarily for still photography. While a similar ability for video would be nice to have, I understand that it would either have to be restricted to more or less fixed crop ratios or use scaling or "digital zoom" in order to deliver standards-compliant video, which would reduce its appeal somewhat.

Comment: Just to confirm… Cadrage would be fine if it saved at 4MP rather than expanding to fit? [It's not that I know of anything suitable, I'm just trying to clarify your requirement]. I'm also trying to figure out how Cadrage can sit a virtual Nikkor 18mm on a Hasselblad medium format, which it appears to claim it can do. ;)

Comment: That's correct – Cadrage would do if it didn't expand the image to fit the native sensor size. An ideal solution would also have the UX of a camera app, but Cadrage isn't too bad.

Comment: As for the medium format simulation you mention, I think I once read that Cadrage supports some sort of a third-party wideangle extension that's attached in front of the built-in camera lens and provides the necessary shortening of focal length.